# How to specify key as parameter in a function using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Learning about functions and can't understand why they break when I try to make a key a parameter. They work fine when making a value a parameter but not the key. What don't I know about JavaScript or jQuery that is breaking this?

example:

```
function box(e, a, q, r) {
    $('div').animate({
        r : e,
        'height' : a
    }, q);
}

box('200px', '200px', 500, 'width');
```

if I remove the 4th parameter r, it works fine. but something about making a key in a key/value pair doesn't work. Teach me, internet.

Answer (score 5):

In object literal all keys are identified as strings. To use variables as keys for JS objects use square bracket notation:

```
function box(e, a, q, r) {
    var config = {
        height : a
    };
    config[r] = e;

    $("div").animate(config, q);
}
```

**READ MORE:** http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html#vId

Comment: Should height be enclosed in quotes? I was under the impression that is only required for reserved keywords.

Comment: @BradM It doesn't really matter.

Comment: yeah, I got burned before for not using quotes, so I just use them all the time now.

Comment: Sometimes you may use a reserved word as a key. Mostly it can make problem in IE, where, for example, `class` is a reserved word. So when you use `{ class : "value" }` IE may raise a syntax error. For such cases you should surround key name in quotes.

Comment: Or avoid using keywords.  Prepend them if you like: `{elem_class:"value"}`

Comment: @BradM Quotes are also required for invalid identifiers - like a string containing special characters or starting with a number (and not containing non-numbers)...`testing-key` or `1a`

Comment: @VisioN hmm. I wish I was smart enough to understand your answer but I am too noob. For now I'll keep wondering why it's so much harder for keys than for values...